# Opencart htaccess to reduce server respond time and caching

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, opencart

My website has Home page speed problem, mainly the server respond time(TTFB) is slow, I'm trying to fix it and also I came up with the following htaccess caching codes which solved some of the problem, after using this code, I had a problem with the admin backend caching system, the modification refresh function is not working, but when I delete the codes in htaccess file things back to normal...
My question is

1. How to exclude the admin backend from this code and is this
   completely correct code for my website to use?
2. My website is https and has two themes one is desktop them and mobile theme,
   https:[www.website.com/index.php?route=common/home](http://www.website.com/index.php?route=common/home)  was redirected to https:[www.website.com](http://www.website.com) with an extension did the job.
   Mobile theme original url is: "/index.php?route=extension/mobile/home"
   I want to make it into  "https://www.website.com/mobile"

P.S: Opencart Version 3.0.3.2

Any help & correction is appreciated

the htaccess code:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled.

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks


# Rabbit Rabbit Security Upgrade 02/03/2016
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# Prevent Directory listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
## For apache 2.2 and older, replace "Require all denied" with these two lines :
# Order deny,allow
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# disable etags
FileETag none

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]


# Enable Gzip Compression
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon

# Remove Browser Bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# cache gif, jpg, and png files for one week
<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>

# Leverage Browser Caching
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 week"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
 ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 week"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Comment: Whilst client-side caching will naturally help with load time for subsequent visits, it's not going to make any difference to the TTFB, if that is what you are suggesting?

Comment: at least that i can cache user pages for browsing, the problem is the theme i'm using has so many CSS and JS files, i tried to minify and compress them but i can't reduce the number of files. So i'm doing htaccess caching just as a temporary solution.

Comment: "How to exclude the admin backend from this code" - from _ALL_ this code? Or just the caching and compressing code, OR just the caching code? And what identifies the "admin backend"? Is this accessible from a specific URL-path OR physical subdirectory?

Comment: from ALL this code will be fine if it's easier to do, Or just the caching and compressing code because the backend is working fine no need for caching.in another platform, someone said add htaccess file to the admin folder.

Comment: i check which was causing the problem, when i delete the following code, ( # Leverage Browser Caching)  things work just fine, when i add it, the admin backend also being cached and i can't do refresh for modifications.